# Cassandra select query with Bind Variables in java8

Tags: java-8, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver, bind-variables

I am trying to execute a Cassandra query in Java8.
My query is
SELECT * FROM  customer where aor='north'
and I execute it with
session.execute(query)
and got correct answer.
But then I changed my query to **SELECT * FROM  customer where aor=?**

```
PreparedStatement statement =  session.prepare(query);
BoundStatement boundStatement = statement.bind("'north'");
ResultSet results = session.execute(boundStatement);
for (Row row : results) {
            System.out.println(row.toString());
        }
```

This is not working. No errors showing but I am not getting any result.

Can someone please help

Comment: You should probably change `statement.bind("'north'");` -> `statement.bind("north");`

Comment: @ByeBye Thankyou so much for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `statement.bind("'north'");` it means that you want literally find `'north'`.

Just change your string to `north` and it will work as you wanted